# Redirect to custom URL using React Router

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, react-router

I'm using React and React Router to build the front-end of a site that uses Wordpress as a back-end. The front-end is entirely made in React except for a few pages, such as the login page, for which I have to use a standard Wordpress theme. So if my site is `http://example.com`, when I go to `http://example.com/login` I need to 'switch' to the Wordpress theme.

How can I do this with React Router? Is that even possible?

Here are my current routes:

```
class App extends React.Component {  

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <MainHeader />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={ HomePage } />
                    <Route path="/you/" component={ UserDashboard } />
                    <Route path="/search/" component={ SearchForm } />
                    <Route path="/:slug" component={ SinglePost } />
                    <Route render={ () => { return( <p>Not Found</p> ) } } />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        );

    }

}
```